# Selecionar placa de rede na VirtualBox para captura de pacotes [JPCAP]

Tags: redes, virtualbox

Boa tarde.

Pessoal, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em java para a captura de pacotes utilizando o JPCAP. Estou utilizando uma maquina virtual, porem não estou conseguindo selecionar a interface de rede para que meu programa capture os pacotes de rede. Tem como fazer isso utilizando a maquina virtual? Fiz o teste do código na maquina local e está funcionando como o desejado.

Em resumo, seria a utilização do JPCAP no VirtualBox.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Nas configurações de rede da máquina virtual, selecione que ela deve estar conectada em modo bridge, assim ela terá um ip próprio dentro da sua rede.

[image: Virtual Box - Configurações]

Comment: Eu já fiz isso. Porem não consigo capturar nenhum pacote de rede.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. O identificador da placa utilizada pelo Virtualbox é 0 (zero).

JpcapCaptor captor = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(interfaces[0], 65535, false, 200);